# multiple System Sounds are seen on win 7

Tags: winapi, audio

Sometimes, on my win 7 OS, I see multiple System Sounds icons in volume mixer. Some of my applications are using SimpleAudioVolume APIs to mute the system sounds. Can anyone tell me why I see multiple "system sounds" icons in Volume Mixer? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing "system sounds sessions", audio session with special status of system-notification sounds, which Windows distinguishes from other sessions. There might be more than one session of this type at a time. Programmatically, you can identify those sessions using [`IAudioSessionControl2::IsSystemSoundsSession` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368257).